# When extending a backbone view, is there a way to not render a tagname?

Tags: backbone.js, tagname

I am trying to use the JQueryUI accordion script with my backbone view.
In my template, i have an h3 and div tag, one for the accordion title, and one for content.
Since the extended view puts a div around the each templated item, the classes that the accordion script adds are not on the correct tags.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can just put your own placeholder on your page like this:

```
<div id="placeholder"/>
```

In your backbone view code, do NOT define el. Then define the view's el when you create the backbone view:

```
var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#placeholder") });
```