# backbone js append view

Tags: html, templates, view, backbone.js, render

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Backbone js: How to remove extra tag in view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663895/backbone-js-how-to-remove-extra-tag-in-view)

How come whenever I append a new backbone view to an HTML element, it automatically surrounds this view with a `<div> </div>`?

For example I have a table in my HTML page

```
<table class="table table-hover">

    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbl">    
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Now in my backbone controller, I perform the following

```
$("#tbl").append(new tblview().render().el);
```

and in the actual view's HTML template I have

tblview.html

```
<tr>
    <td>entry3</td>
    <td>entry4</td>
</tr>
```

Now when i look at this in the browser, and inspect the html element.. it renders like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">

    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbl">
        <div>
              <tr>
                <td>entry3</td>
                <td>entry4</td>
              </tr>

        </div>  
    </tbody>

</table>
```

and thus is becomes all out of line? How can I fix this issue??
I want it to render the view without these extra `<div>  </div>` in the table.

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982785/when-extending-a-backbone-view-is-there-a-way-to-not-render-a-tagname

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195242/extra-wrappers-in-backbone-and-marionette

Comment: this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601966/how-to-avoid-template-wrapping-with-empty-div-in-backbone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894253/backbone-js-turning-off-wrap-by-div-in-render ... i could go on for a while :P

Answer (score 2):

Backbone automatically create a `div` to surround any view. To overwritte the default, you need to set the `tagName` attribute when you extend a view. http://backbonejs.org/#View-extend

```
Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "tr"
});
```

Comment: Not yet, but I'm happy this helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

Your template doesn't need to include the `tr` tags. `tblView` should have `tagName` set to `tr`.

Comment: thanks, fixed my issue straight away:]  mymy how have i been using backbone for last 1 year and not known this...